# Spinner and hashmap in android

Tags: android, hashmap, android-spinner

When display data from `HasMap` with key and value in `Spinner` it appear in one line. So how can I display data from `HashMap` in multiple line?

This is my try.

```
mydb = new DBHelper(this);
Studentcourses=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

HashMap<Integer,String> courses=mydb.getAllStudent_Course(std_id);

ArrayAdapter<HashMap<Integer, String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<Integer,String>>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.add(courses);
Studentcourses.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: can you share code for your getAllStudent_Course()  function

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayAdapter` by its own can't write two lines, besides you use `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`
so you need to make own custom adapter like there

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/06/custom-arrayadapter-for-spinner-with.html

(just change the `imageView` to `textview` in layout)